# Is it possible to whitelist JSON (as text) in Rails' strong parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, strong-parameters

Let's say I have this JSON:

```
{
   name: 'David',
   tags: { 
     is_confused: true 
   }
}
```

and in a certain model (i.e. User), I can save this directly... but my tags object needs to be saved in a Text column which will later serialize to JSON. Is there any way to do this with strong parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force tags to json before permitting it as a string with strong parameters.

Assuming your object is named "params":

```
params[:tags] = params[:tags].permit(:is_confused).to_json
final_data = params.permit(:name, :tags)
```

This uses strong parameters to check the tags field before turning it to a json string so that you can save it as text (and use strong parameters to ensure that it's a string).

Comment: minor nitpick: strong params don't ensure it's a _string_. Only that it's a simple type (not array or hash).

Comment: Agreed, but we just changed it to a string with the command before, so we can be pretty sure it's going to be a string... *shifty eyes* *fingers crossed*

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was trying this option but for a reason I'm not aware of, using "require" in the second line was not applying the assignment in the first line (I had require in my code).